is structural pattern matching and interface methods possible in C
I read the top 7 SO questions on the topic of pattern matching but they all talk about string pattern matching which is not what I am after.
I want to write a compiler and need a language with pattern matching, sum types and one that can easily traverse an Abstract Syntax Tree and evaluate it.
The last point is easiest when the AST is modeled as a tree and every component is a subclass of a tree node. Every tree node implements an interface "evaluate" that evaluates the specific expression stored in this node. Clearly object oriented programming with methods instead of functions is useful here.
My question: is C suited for all of the above? How can I achieve both pattern matching and these interface-like evaluation methods?
Thanks!

C is a very simple language.  If you have the skills to build a compiler,  you would have understood C basics in an hour or so. So it appears that you're rather overestimating your skills. No language feature will make compiler construction easy.

If you think "object oriented programming with methods" is useful here, perhaps C is not the first choice. For example, C++ was originally created to get this. On the other hand, parsing and traversing an AST are the easy parts of writing a compiler, so perhaps not the only thing to consider. (And C compilers written in C are not at all unusual).

@BoP But is it possible to do pattern matching and have something like interface methods in C?

@MSalters But is it possible to do pattern matching and have something like interface methods in C?

@Max - For some definition of "possible" it is possible, but not something I would like to do (or use). Remember that Bjarne originally tried this using macros in C, and then did it again using a fancy pre-processor. Then he gave up and wrote a proper compiler to support classes and "methods" (which he called member-functions). And he had access to K & R in person when he did his work, so it is not that he didn't know C properly :-).
